# How do I create a temporary table with identity column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am planning to create a temporary table with an extra column(`Id`) that will generate a number sequentially when new data is added

```
Id    LastName    FirstNmae
...  ..........  ...........
1        A           B
2        C           D
```

The column `Id` should maintain order for the insert logic ie, `Id` should increment each time an insert occurs. I also need to retrieve data from the table according to the order of `Id`. How do I do that?

Comment: A great situation. If you don't select then why you are trying to order the table, I think you want indexing.eager to know the reason.

Comment: I will select, but without order by

Comment: make "num" as `Primary Key`. And add `clustered index` on `num` if you don't have.

Comment: if you don't select there's no point in ordering. also if you don't select how do you know the rows are ordered? maybe you should explain the need behind this request...

Comment: Why are you not able/willing to put ORDER BY in your SELECT?

Comment: **The order of results is not guaranteed without an `ORDER BY` clause.** Result order may change at the optimizer's whim, change in parallelism, with any software update, ... . Creating an index does not force any particular order on the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the table set `NUM`  as `IDENTITY` field

```
CREATE TABLE #Table
(
NUM int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
FirstName varchar(255),
LastName varchar(255)
)
```

Now insert leaving `NUM` column(it will automatically increment

```
INSERT INTO #Table VALUES('A','B')
INSERT INTO #Table VALUES('C','D')
```

[image]